# What is the difference between CountVectorizer token counts and TfidfTransformer with use_idf set to False?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

We can use CountVectorizer to count the number of times a word occurs in a corpus:

```
# Tokenizing text
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(twenty_train.data)
```

If we convert this to a data frame, we can see what the tokens look like:

[image]

For example, the 35,780th word of the 3rd document occurs twice.

We can use TfidfTransformer to count the number of times a word occurs in a corpus (only the term frequency and not the inverse) as follows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)
```

Converting this to a data frame, we get:

[image]

We can see the representation is different. The TF is shown as 0.15523. Why is this different than the token count using CountVectorizer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually, the documentation was pretty clear. I'll keep it posted in case someone else searches before reading:

The `TfidfTransformer` **transforms a count matrix** to a **normalized** tf or tf-idf representation. So although both the `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfTransformer` (with `use_idf=False`) produce term frequencies, `TfidfTransformer` is normalizing the count.

Answer (score 15):

Speaking only for myself, I find it so much easier to work out these things by using the simplest examples I can find, rather than those big monster texts that `sklearn` provides. The monster texts are useful later, but in figuring out the difference between `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfVectorizer` the sheer volume of words aren't very helpful when you're trying to pick through the bones to see what's connected to what.

Consider, then, a case where we create two vectorizers, and two very simple examples:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
tv = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

a = "cat hat bat splat cat bat hat mat cat"
b = "cat mat cat sat"
```

Calling `fit_transform()` on either vectorizer with our list of documents, `[a,b]`, as the argument in each case, returns the same type of object – a 2x6 sparse matrix with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format. The only difference is that the `TfidfVectorizer()` returns floats while the `CountVectorizer()` returns ints. And that’s to be expected – as explained in the documentation quoted above, `TfidfVectorizer()` assigns a score while `CountVectorizer()` counts.

```
cv_score = cv.fit_transform([a, b])
cv_score
>>> <2x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

tv_score = tv.fit_transform([a, b])
tv_score
>>> <2x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The difference between our scoring matrices is easier to see if we iterate over them – hence the choosing of the nice short text for our example. First, we’ll write a function to convert our spare matrices to good old lists.

```
def matrix_to_list(matrix):
    matrix = matrix.toarray()
    return matrix.tolist()

cv_score_list = matrix_to_list(cv_score)
cv_score_list
>>> [[2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0]]

tv_score_list = matrix_to_list(tv_score)
tv_score_list
>>> [[0.5333344767907123,
  0.5692078092660131,
  0.5333344767907123,
  0.18973593642200434,
  0.0,
  0.26666723839535617],
 [0.0, 0.7572644142929534, 0.0, 0.3786322071464767, 0.5321543559503558, 0.0]]
```

Each list contains two lists as elements – the score for `a` and `b` respectively in the case of the `tv_score_list`, and the word count for `a` and `b` respectively in the case of the `cv_score_list`. We couple this with the knowledge that the (alphabetical) order of words if we call `.get_feature_names()` on either vectorizer matches the order of the scoring. As such, we can iterate nicely over our four lists (2x2) and our word list to make a useful table:

```
print("tfidf_a  tfidf_b  count_a count_b   word")
print("-"*41)
for i in range(6):
    print("  {:.3f}    {:.3f}        {:}       {:}   {:}".format(tv_score_list[0][i],
                                               tv_score_list[1][i],
                                               cv_score_list[0][i],
                                               cv_score_list[1][i],
                                               cv.get_feature_names()[i]))

tfidf_a  tfidf_b  count_a count_b   word
-----------------------------------------
  0.533    0.000        2       0   bat
  0.569    0.757        3       2   cat
  0.533    0.000        2       0   hat
  0.190    0.379        1       1   mat
  0.000    0.532        0       1   sat
  0.267    0.000        1       0   splat
```

Looking at the table allows us to get a feel for how the `tfidf` algorithm works. For instance, *splat* appears once in `a` and not at all in `b`, while `sat` appears once in `b` and not at all in `a`. Yet *splat* scores 0.267 while *sat* scores 0.532. Also notice that while *mat* appears in both lists, it scores 0.19 for `a` and 0.379 for `b`. This is the algorithm’s distinction between term frequency and document frequency at work.

Thanks for bearing with me. I hope this some help to someone.

Answer (score 2):

Transform a count matrix to a normalized tf or tf-idf representation

Tf means term-frequency while tf-idf means term-frequency times inverse document-frequency. This is a common term weighting scheme in information retrieval, that has also found good use in document classification.